# app install event is not triggred in Facebook insight

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK v4.0.1 in Android Application for login and events both working fine but I'm missing only one event that is App install as com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(context, YOUR_APP_ID) deprecated I'm using com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(context, YOUR_APP_ID);
but this records App Launch event not App Install and for demographic data my client wants App Install event.Please help me on this..

Comment: The first time an app launches, it will record as an install.

Comment: Thanks Ming LI for response but is recording as App Launch not App Install

Comment: Can you outline how you're testing an app install? Are you installing on a new device every time?

Comment: My app is in development stage so I have to do adb install *.apk to install into device i could see app launches but not app install,Thanks Ming LI

Comment: For better understanding I uploaded 2 images please have a check on this [fb1.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/th355eg0amo7uo2/fb1.png?dl=0) and [fb2.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7annr891pgem8kp/fb2.png?dl=0) in fb1.png I couldn't see any update about android and in fb2.png I'm missing app install event for android..Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you try on a real device (not emulator) with the Facebook app installed? Sometimes it could take a long time for our backend systems to register an "unknown" install.